# Remove numbers from array of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, string

I have an array that looks like this:

```
["lorem", "ipsum", "1734", "dolor", "1", "301", "et", "4102", "92"]
```

Is there a way to remove all the numbers in the array, even though they're stored as strings, so that I'd be left with this:

```
["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "et"]
```

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Is there ever a possibility of having float strings `"0.12"` or even scientific notation `"3.4e-10"`? Can some strings have multiple lines in them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regexp pattern

```
s = ["lorem", "ipsum", "1734", "dolor", "1", "301", "et", "4102", "92"]
s.reject { |l| l =~ /\A\d+\z/ }
# => ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "et"]
```

Comment: There's also `reject { |w| w !~ /\D/ }` if you don't mind triple negatives (reject, doesn't match, not digit).

Comment: @muistooshort In that case you can use select instead of reject. ;)

Comment: But then you're stuck with the anchors again and you don't get to make everyone question the difference between genius and insanity :)

Answer (score 4):

```
s = ["lorem", "ipsum", "1734", "dolor", "1", "301", "et", "4102", "92"]
s.reject{|s| s.match(/^\d+$/) }
```

Answer (score 3):

If all your strings are just integers, @Simone's answer will work nicely.

If you need to check for all numeric representations (floats and scientific notation) then you can:

```
s = %w[ foo 134 0.2 3e-3 bar ]
s.reject!{ |str| Float(str) rescue false }
p s
#=> ["foo", "bar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I can say is: REGEX match

1. Loop though all the items
2. Then use this:

   ```
   txt='Your string'

   re1='(\\d+)'    # Integer Number 1

   re=(re1)
   m=Regexp.new(re,Regexp::IGNORECASE);
   if m.match(txt)
       int1=m.match(txt)[1];
       # REMOVE THE ITEM HERE
   end
   ```